How can I close the vue modal when I update the data?
I am new to vue.js. I write this for pencil
<i
                              class="mdi mdi-pencil"
                              @click.prevent="$bvModal.show(type.title)"
                            ></i>

This for modal
<b-modal
                              :id="type.title"
                              ref="modal"
                              title="Update holiday"
                              centered
                              hide-footer
                            >
                              <FormModal
                                cardTitle="Update holiday"
                                description=""
                                :value="type.title"
                                action="update"
                                @formData="parseFormData"
                                :holidayTypeID="type.id"
                              ></FormModal>

and this is the function
holidaysTypeUpdate(value, holidayID) {
  this.$refs["modal"][0].hide();

  session
    .put(`api/holidays/holiday-type/${holidayID}/action/`, {
      title: value,
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.alertSchema = {
        alertVariant: "success",
        alertMsg: "Holiday updated",
        show: true,
      };
      this.$bvModal.hide("type.title");
      this.fetchHolidayTypes();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e.response.data);
    });
},

When I press the button the data updated but the modal don't close. What can I do in order to close the modal when I update the data?

Have you tried this.$refs['modal'].hide() or maybe this.$bvModal.hide("#type.title") ?

I tried both of them but they don't work

Okay, have you tried this.$nextTick(() => {         this.$bvModal.hide('type.title') }) ?

I tried but doesn't work

It's .hide(type.title), not .hide("type.title")

When I write this.hide(type.title); I have error

...what error?  you need to provide a string of the modal id according to the documentation.  the id is a variable type.title, therefore it's value must be passed and/or used in the hide function.

1 error found.
@ ./src/router/routes.js 121:11-53
@ ./src/router/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.10.115:8081/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

You try to hide modal using this.$bvModal.hide("type.title"), but this is not closing the modal because it seems you are passing the modal as string("type.title"), instead of the actual modal ID. Try remove quote so it will looks like this.$bvModal.hide(type.title)
Or, since you are using a ref, you can just simply do this.$refs.modal.hide();

Instead of this.$bvModal.hide("type.title") I tried this.$bvModal.hide(value); but I have the same problem when I press update without change anything the modal close but when I change something and press update the data change but modal don't close. I also tried this.$refs.modal.hide(); but doesn't work.

Now I try this
holidaysTypeUpdate(value, holidayID) {
  console.log("holiday is", holidayID, value);
  this.$bvModal.hide(value);
  session
    .put(`api/holidays/holiday-type/${holidayID}/action/`, {
      title: value,
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.alertSchema = {
        alertVariant: "success",
        alertMsg: "Holiday updated",
        show: true,
      };
      this.$bvModal.hide('type.title');
      this.fetchHolidayTypes();
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e.response.data);
    });
},

But when I don't change something and press update the modal close but when I change something and press update the modal doesn't close.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
